# When performing SSO with SAML, can I use the same certificate for signing AND encryption?

Tags: encryption, single-sign-on, saml

Is there a good reason to have a separate certificate for encrypting a SAML response and signing the SAML response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When encrypting the SAML response it will be encrypted using the public key for the receivers certificate. The response will be signed with the private key of the sender.

As one operation is done with the senders certificate and one is done with the receivers the certificates will typically not be the same. There is no technical limitation though.

Comment: Ime its very common for saml entities to register the same cert for both in their metadata

Comment: Yes it is and there is no technical limitation not to, but it is not best practice.